# What is the meaning of the first gain in the block diagram?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, diagram

I have do design a circuit based on the block diagram below. I know how to design the PID part but I don't understand what the K=2 is. For the PID I have made the following:

[image: PID]
[image]

Comment: In my mind, I'd interpret it as a gain factor that applies to an error difference. Somewhere, you need to design something that takes a setpoint and the process output and creates a difference value between them. I would guess you want to make that section provide a gain of 2 on the difference before feeding that result to the rest of the PID controller. Probably just a different selection of resistor values in that error section.

Comment: What @jonk said.  It's not uncommon to have a master gain control on a PID controller.  I'm a bit troubled by the fact that those gains have no units, though.  Presumably the \$K_i\$ and \$K_d\$ are in seconds, but you can't really be sure.

Comment: Your schematic is wrong. A PID loop has a LPF (I) and a HPF (P) with a bit of bypass (P). The sum of all 3 is used to control a motor or actuator. A PID is tuned to match the very slow mechanical parameters of a physical device to ultra-fast electronics (FPGA/MPU/CPU), else the loop is unstable.